# Clarify about the connecting homomorphisms and the snake lemma

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, diagram-chasing

In class we said (without proof) that given a an exact sequence of chain complexes $$0\to \mathcal A\xrightarrow{f} \mathcal B\xrightarrow g \mathcal C\to 0$$ one can construct the long exact sequence $$\dots \xrightarrow{\delta_{q+1}} H(A_q)\xrightarrow{f_q} H(B_q) \xrightarrow{g_q} H(C_q)\xrightarrow{\delta_q} H(A_{q-1})\xrightarrow{f_{q-1}}\dots  \ ,$$ where the $\delta _q$ are the connecting homomorphisms. Now, I read on wikipedia how these homomorphisms are obtained, but I don't understand well why the snake lemma works in this context. In fact the vertical maps of the lemma here are the boundary homomorphisms of the corresponding complex (let's call them $\alpha_q$, $\beta_q$ and $\gamma_q$ for respectively $A_q$, $B_q$ and $C_q$); and the lemma builds a homomorphism from $\text{ker}(C_q)$ to $\text {coker }(\alpha_q)$. However, shouldn't we need an homomorphism that goes in $H(A_{q-1})\subseteq\text {coker }(\alpha_q)$? My idea is that when the vertical maps are the boundary homomorphisms one can prove that $\text {Im} (\delta_q)\subseteq \text{ker} (\alpha_{q-1})$, but I first want to know if I'm approaching things from the right point of view. Thanks for any clarify

Comment: Watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hc4HjLrHKLU&t=43s) might help.

Comment: @Saikat I was really and truly expecting this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etbcKWEKnvg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the snake lemma not to
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
& & A_q & \rightarrow & B_q & \rightarrow & C_q & \rightarrow & 0 \\ 
& & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
0 & \rightarrow & A_{q-1} & \rightarrow & B_{q-1} & \rightarrow & C_{q-1}, & & 
\end{array}$$
but to
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
& & \coker(\alpha_{q+1}) & \rightarrow & \coker(\beta_{q+1}) & \rightarrow & \coker(\gamma_{q+1}) & \rightarrow & 0 \\ 
& & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
0 & \rightarrow & \ker(\alpha_{q-1}) & \rightarrow & \ker(\beta_{q-1}) & \rightarrow & \ker(\gamma_{q-1}). & & 
\end{array}$$

Make sure you see where the maps come from, that the diagram commutes, and that the rows are exact.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I don't understand... The cokernels that you wrote are contained in $A_{q-1}$, $B_{q-1}$ and $C_{q-1}$. Shouldn't I have something of the $q$-th level in the upper row?

Comment: @Dorian Corrected, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's clear. So one just needs the commutativity at every level, but is not necessary that the compositions of the vertical maps are zero (like for boundary maps) right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "commutativity at every level", and I don't see which vertical maps you want to compose.  In any case, the vertical maps in either diagram are given by the boundary maps.  Indeed, the second diagram is a "subquotient" of the first.